# Driver Description printer

Tags: command-line, drivers, bash

I have written a small one-liner which prints all the loaded kernel modules along with their one-line description.

Answer (score 0):

It combines `lsmod` and `modinfo` utilities. I think its pretty useful if you want a summary of drivers used by your system.

[Here is the link to the gist](https://gist.github.com/praton1729/25132d523ab965c5a185e0211d9ebfcd)